# Custom map style in MapKit

Tags: ios, google-maps, mapkit, mapbox, cloudmade

I am looking for a way to implement a custom map style in iOS 7, just like you can do with [Google Maps](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/styling). I have found some posts saying that this is not possible with MapKit, but they are all posted a while back. To clarify, by style I am talking about custom colors and preferably also fonts. Example of custom Google Map style below.

[image]
<sub>(source: [servendesign.com](http://www.servendesign.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/12/zaarley-custom-google-maps.jpg))</sub>

I would really prefer using MapKit for performance reasons, but if it is not supported I am open to using other frameworks as well. The ones that I have seen are MapBox and Cloudmade, and of course the Google Maps SDK.

Is there a way of doing it with MapKit? If not, what is the best way to go?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`MKMapView` does not expose the properties you're interested in customizing. The Google Maps SDK does support custom colors and icons for markers, which may be sufficient for your purposes.

Edit: Stay tuned for iOS 11, which may offer this level of customization.

Comment: Thanks for the input. Do you know how the Google Maps SDK stand in comparison to native MapKit when it comes to performance?

Comment: I'm no authority, but I cannot discern a major performance difference between the Google Maps SDK demo app and any app using MapKit. YMMV.

Comment: @Marco, performance boost favorable to MapKit or Google Maps SDK?

Comment: @ScottyBlades, my answer is from 2013 and possibly outdated at this point. I have no idea about a performance boost vis-a-vis MapKit or Google Maps SDK.

Answer (score 19):

MKMapView also offers the possibility to use custom tile overlays. Openstreetmap has a great list of tile servers you could use to get a custom map. Of course there is always the possibility to create your own tile overlay set. The process is described in the Openstreetmap wiki [here](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Creating_your_own_tiles).

A possible implementation in Swift could look like this:

**1. Import MapKit**

```
import MapKit
```

**2. Add overlays to map**

```
let overlayPath = self.mapViewModel.overlayURL
let overlay = MKTileOverlay(URLTemplate: overlayPath)
overlay.canReplaceMapContent = true
self.mapView.addOverlay(overlay)
```

**3. Conform to MKMapViewDelegate**

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, MKMapViewDelegate { ... }
```

**4. Implement delegate method to use the correct renderer to display the tiles**

```
func mapView(mapView: MKMapView, rendererForOverlay overlay: MKOverlay) -> MKOverlayRenderer {
    guard let tileOverlay = overlay as? MKTileOverlay else {
        return MKOverlayRenderer(overlay: overlay)
    }
    return MKTileOverlayRenderer(tileOverlay: tileOverlay)
}
```

In the above example overlayURL is taken from the tile server list found on openstreetmap: [OpenstreetMap Tile Servers](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Tile_servers).

For example if you would like to use the stamen map (which has a watercolor style) your url would look like:

```
let overlayURL = "http://tile.stamen.com/watercolor/{z}/{x}/{y}.jpg"
```

If you are searching for a dark-mode map you probably go best with Carto Dark: `http://a.basemaps.cartocdn.com/dark_all/${z}/${x}/${y}.png`.

See that the above URLs has no SSL support (HTTP). Therefore you will need to allow insecure HTTP requests to this specific URL by adding the `App Transport Security Settings` in your Info.plist. For further information have a look at [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30731785/how-do-i-load-an-http-url-with-app-transport-security-enabled-in-ios-9).

Comment: Hello @dehlen, thanks for this helpful answer. Quick Q: where in my MapViewController do I put this code (particularly the block in point 2, as I'm getting red error msgs wherever I place it.

Comment: @DimitriT you can put it in your viewDidLoad func for example.

Comment: thank you Dehlen. If you may be so kind as to explain for a beginner like me - what code am I supposed to add, to get the mapViewModel class as I am getting the error 'use of unresolved identifier MapViewModel'. I presume I add a new swift file, wondering how to add this. Just got the hang of the maps and annotations- Any tips on this class would be a great help.

Comment: @DimitriT Its just a class where I stored a constant pointing to the right tileserver URL. You can replace `let overlayPath = self.mapViewModel.overlayURL` with `let overlayPath = "http://tile.stamen.com/watercolor/{z}/{x}/{y}.jpg"
`like I stated in the answer above.

Comment: How can I get those variables (x, y, z)?

Comment: You don't need them. They are aubstituted by the mapview itself. Just keep the placeholders in the string.

Comment: You would need to download the tile data and bundle it with your app. The template url could then be a file url rather than a http url.

Comment: Example: `let bundleURL = Bundle.main.bundleURL.absoluteString
        let overlayURL = bundleURL.appending("/tile-data/{z}/{x}/{y}.png")
        self.tileOverlay = MKTileOverlay(URLTemplate: overlayURL)` where your downloaded tile data is in a folder called tile-data and this folder is added to your app bundle.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question how to change the background color of MKMapView. Even you used customized tile, but the map background is still not changed. For example, I only show a map for a country through customized tiles. But the area outside of this country will be in map original background.

Answer (score 2):

Another option is [MBXMapKit](http://mapbox.com/mbxmapkit), which is a MapBox library built atop Apple's MapKit, though it's geared for MapBox layers. It is separate from the [MapBox iOS SDK](http://mapbox.com/mapbox-ios-sdk), which is a ground-up rewrite meant to work like MapKit but not based on it.

Comment: Thank you, I will look into it. I do like the fact that it is built upon MapKit.

Answer (score 0):

I created a class that allows one to create a custom style.

This particular implementation looks like this:

[image]

It has one small drawback: when panning, new tiles are loaded with the default colors first, the overlay only kicks in after a fraction of a second. Otherwise it's serving me right.

```
struct CustomOverlayMap: UIViewControllerRepresentable { // SwiftUI representation
    func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> CustomOverlayMapViewController {
        let x = CustomOverlayMapViewController()
        x.view.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
        return x
    }
    
    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: CustomOverlayMapViewController, context: Context) {
        uiViewController.mapView.frame = uiViewController.view.frame
    }
    
    typealias UIViewControllerType = CustomOverlayMapViewController
}

class CustomOverlayMapViewController: UIViewController, MKMapViewDelegate {
    let mapView = MKMapView()
    
    let wholeWorldPolygon = [
        (90, 0),
        (90, 180),
        (-90, 180),
        (-90, 0),
        (-90, -180),
        (90, -180)
    ].map {
        CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: $0.0, longitude: $0.1)
    }
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        mapView.mapType = .standard
        mapView.showsTraffic = false
        mapView.showsPointsOfInterest = false
        mapView.showsBuildings = false
        mapView.pointOfInterestFilter = MKPointOfInterestFilter(excluding: [.nationalPark, .park])
        
        mapView.delegate = self
        
        let overlays = [polygonFrom(wholeWorldPolygon, title: "one"), polygonFrom(wholeWorldPolygon, title: "two"), polygonFrom(wholeWorldPolygon, title: "three")]
        mapView.addOverlays(overlays, level: .aboveRoads)
        
        mapView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
        self.view.addSubview(mapView)
    }
    
    func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, rendererFor overlay: MKOverlay) -> MKOverlayRenderer {
        guard(overlay is MKPolygon) else { return MKOverlayRenderer() }
        
        let renderer = MKPolygonRenderer.init(polygon: overlay as! MKPolygon)
        
        switch renderer.polygon.title {
            case "one":
                renderer.fillColor = .red
                
                if #available(iOS 16.0, *) {
                    renderer.blendMode = .saturation
                } else {
                    // Fallback on earlier versions
                }
                renderer.alpha = 1.0
                
            case "two":
                renderer.fillColor = .red
                
                if #available(iOS 16.0, *) {
                    renderer.blendMode = .lighten
                } else {
                    // Fallback on earlier versions
                }
                renderer.alpha = 1.0
                
            case "three":
                renderer.lineWidth = 1.0
                renderer.fillColor = .red
                
                if #available(iOS 16.0, *) {
                    renderer.blendMode = .color
                } else {
                    // Fallback on earlier versions
                }
                renderer.alpha = 1.0
                
            default: break
        }
        
        return renderer
    }
    
    func polygonFrom(_ points: [CLLocationCoordinate2D], title: String? = nil) -> MKPolygon {
        let result: MKPolygon = MKPolygon(coordinates: points, count: points.count)
        result.title = title
        
        return result
    }
}
```