# Display Traffic in iOS7 app using MapKit

Tags: ios7, mkmapview, mapkit

Is there a way I can display Traffic in an iOS7 app using Mapkit? I believe it can be achieved if Google Maps SDK for iOS is used but can it be done using iOS's Mapkit?

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure you've noticed that the `MKMapView`'s `showsTraffic` is only available on `iOS 9+`.

```
mapView.showsTraffic = true
```

In order to achieve this on a pre-iOS 9 application, you'll need to bring in a map tile from an external source to display the traffic. There are several services that do this, I'm not sure what their pricing/free products are. It looks like [Here](https://developer.here.com/documentation/map-tile/dev_guide/topics/traffic-tiles.html) has a good api for it. Once you find the service you want to use to serve your traffic map tiles, you can integrate them into your map app using an MKTileOverlay: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38722623/12470155