# How to change Apple Map (MKMapView) background colors?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, mkmapview, background-color

[image]

I've Required an iOS application with a black theme, and would really like to make the displayed Apple Map also in black colors.

I see nothing in the native documentation that talks about changing look for MKMapView.

I've Googled the topic and tried to change MKOverlayView.But, I couldn't find anything.

Is this even possible? Can I change the background colors of the Apple Map.

Thank you.

Comment: not possible yet

Comment: @Lu_ then how can achieve this?

Comment: google maps? any other maps library

Comment: @Lu_ please suggest any library if you know.

Comment: You can use hybrid mapTye for black theme

Comment: @HarshalValanda how ? give some hint please.

Comment: I would try this https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/styling

Comment: @Lu_ but i use only apple map.

Comment: How is it a black theme? show us a screenshot.

Comment: did you saw my first comment? and you ask to suggest library

Comment: @KosukeOgawa see update question.

Comment: @DixitAkabari Any luck?

Comment: @DixitAkabari Are you done with integrating dark mode bro?

Comment: @AnuragSharma not using apple map but if you can use google map then go it because i did this using google map.

Answer (score 0):

You can customize map using `MapBoxKit`

https://www.mapbox.com/ios-sdk/api/3.6.4/runtime-styling.html

In `Mapkit` you can only set dark mode as hybrid as follow:

in viewDidLoad write below code:-

```
 mapView.mapType = .Hybrid
```

[image]

Need to add `Privacy - Photo Library Usage Description` in  `info.plist`

also you can set from IB as above:-

[image]

Comment: and this is a dark mode?

Comment: It is only possible as you want dark theme. You can not do it as other way.

Comment: then you should go with custom tile overlay. Did you try it? MKMapView also offers the possibility to use custom tile overlays.

Comment: @arpita how ? give some hint please.

Comment: May be below will help you

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20273995/custom-map-style-in-mapkit

Comment: @HarshalValanda Bro,  MapBox is not free.