# Change MKMapView Default Background Color

Tags: swift, mkmapview, android-mapview, tiles

I’m currently loading a set of very dark grey tiles over a MKMapView. Everything works correctly but on slower connections there is an expected delay for the tile loading process. With this delay there’s a stark contrast between the currently loaded gray tiles and the default light yellow/orange background of the mapview.

I’m wondering if there’s a way to override the default background color for a map view to a dark grey therefore minimizing the visual impact of the tile delay.

Our project doesn’t have the ability to migrate to MapBox or any of the other map alternatives. Any insight would be appreciated.

Comment: Looking at documentation, I don't see any properties that do what you describe. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mapkit/mkmapview#

Comment: Related? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46783527/how-to-change-apple-map-mkmapview-background-colors

Comment: I didn’t see any publicly available properties to modifier either but there has to be as way to override that color programmatically at some level.

Comment: @Ahmet Unrelated. That post appears to be related to setting up custom map tiles. Not related to overriding the maps default pre-render background color.

Comment: @MikeCarpenter Did you ever find any solution?

Comment: @Magnus I had to move over to MapBox. They provide more vector based styling which prevented slow loading tiles from a raster tile load.

Comment: @MikeCarpenter OK. I recently moved in the other direction. MapBox appears to be more flexible when it comes to these details, but I will stay with MapKit for now.